# Table view cell labels are inconsistent in line break

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a custom table view cell with a label inside. I've noticed that every seventh cell's label breaks first line way too early. All the cells on the screenshot have the same String subsequence (black and red ovals) at the beginning of its label's text.
The mid-cell is the seventh one, as you could have guessed. If I scroll 7 cells down, the result is going to be the same

label configuration:

```
descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0
descriptionLabel.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
```

I have no clue what to do to fix the issue, begging for your help.
Thanks in advance!

[image: screenshot]

Comment: If you just circle text in black and red, the reader won't really be able to tell what the issue is, don't you think?  Show in text what you have and what you want to have.  Not everybody reads cyrillic or whatever that language is.

Comment: The point is that the ovals outline the same String values. What's inside - does not really matter. The line should break the way it does in top and bottom cells

Comment: does you label have fixed height?

Comment: it does not. It has top, leading, trailing "equalTo" constraints, the bottom one is "greaterThanOrEqual"

Comment: It will be great if you show custom cell code, if it is done programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An "orphan" is a single word on a line at the end of a paragraph. In typography, it is considered "bad layout" to leave a word *dangling at the end*.

So, Apple has coded `UILabel` to avoid "orphans."

If you don't mind orphans in your labels, `UITextView` does ***not*** enforce that -- so you could use a `UITextView` (with editing and scrolling disabled).

As you can see in this image, though:

[image]

`UITextView` has default "insets" for the text from the actual frame.

So, here is an `@IBDesignable` subclass that removes the insets:

```
@IBDesignable
class TextViewLabel: UITextView {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect, textContainer: NSTextContainer?) {
        super.init(frame: frame, textContainer: textContainer)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        isScrollEnabled = false
        isEditable = false
        isSelectable = false
        textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
        textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
    }
    
}
```

---

**Edit** *for clarification...*

Here are three default `UILabel`, all the exact same width:

[image]

Note that with label **A**, there is plenty of room at the end of the first line for the word `"an"`, but it gets wrapped to the second line to prevent an orphan -- that is, prevent a **single word** on the second line.

With label **B**, the word `"an"` stays on the first line, because word wrapping results in **two** words on the second line.

As we see with label **C** though, if the text wraps onto ***more than two lines*** the `UILabel` ***will*** allow an orphan -- a single word on the last line.

By replacing the default `UILabel` with the `TextViewLabel` subclass, we can force the two-line wrapping to ignore the "orphan" wrapping:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't explain the odd periodicity bug, but it does fix the issue in my case. Thank you! Will accept it if no explanation shows up

Comment: @AnatolyRudenko - see the **Edit** at the end of my answer for further clarification.