# UILabel truncate functionality of iPhone real device doesn't match with the simulator/emulator

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c

I am trying to set a short text (I want to opt out of analytics tracking) into the UILabel. Inspire of having enough space in the first line (I want to opt out of) the remaining last two words go into the second line. Expected is one word that should go to the second line. But the expected result is ok in the iPhone simulator. The problem is in iPhone real device. It is ridiculous behavior. But it is ok if the text size is large (three or more lines). The iPhone real device (UI) and simulator screenshots are given below. Thanks in advance.

iPhone Real Device Screenshots (Google chrome should render properly):

[image]

iPhone Simulator Screenshots (Google chrome should render properly):

[image]

Screenshots with the corresponding UILabel properties (Google chrome should render properly):

[image]

Code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController1: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var copyrightView: UILabel!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        copyrightView.text = "I want to opt out of analytics tracking."
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you layout the copyrightView inside its parent view ? Check also for the settings about minimum font size in accessibility on iPhone and simulator.

Comment: I added a separate UIView (that contains this UILabel) inside the UIViewController. Actually, it is not a matter, just think simple (A UILabel inside a UIViewController).

Comment: I've tested it in several ways @Ptit

Comment: @AMIT - I pointed you to the explanation in your previous post, which you deleted - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73223544/uilabel-truncate-issue-in-real-device-when-total-text-is-within-2-lines. The explanation is here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68831842/table-view-cell-labels-are-inconsistent-in-line-break

Comment: FYI, I've deleted previous post for my confusion why screeshots wasn't loading. And that post was not completed that time.

Comment: Anyway, I got your point after reading your reference post. Thanks.